# Interesting partition Map with missing HD space

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have the latest generation Macbook Pro running Yosemite, I bought this computer used I don't know if the last person attempted to install linux or what the story is but I believe my partition map is a little weird.

Here it is [image: Partition Map]First off I expected to have only a disk0 I don't know what the disk1 is.  I expected the drive name "Apple_CoreStorage" to be called "Apple_HFS Macintosh HD" like it is on disk1 both of these disks also say that they are 320GB in size although my HD is only 500GB.

There are also 2 recovery drives but when I boot into recovery mode it says that it is loading it from the internet.  I don't know if that is how it works or if it is not recognizing either of these.

My Final problem is with disk0s5 [image: Disk Utility] There are 180GB that I cannot access it is partitioned as disk0s5 I can remove the partition but then it is just mapped as free space.  I try to increase the size of my "Macintosh HD" after removing the 180GB partition but I am not able to.

I feel like both of these problems are deeply intertwined, maybe my map is fine I am unsure but it doesn't look right to me.  Any ideas would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil cs list` executed in Terminal to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk1 is a "virtual device" which resides in disk0s2 (the Apple_CoreStorage Volume Group which actually contains a FileVault volume). You have only one 'physical device' indeed.

Disk0s5 is probably an old Bootcamp installation.

**The clean way (get rid of the 2 `Recovery HDs`):**

1. Make a complete Time Machine backup of `Macintosh HD`.
2. Start to `Internet Recovery Mode` by pressing  <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
3. Start  `Terminal` and enter following command at the Terminal prompt:
   `diskutil cs list`. The output will look like this:

   ```
   CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
   |
   +-- Logical Volume Group 5B8350BF-20EF-4199-82E6-129EFF19E9EB
       =========================================================
       Name:         Macintosh HD
       Status:       Online
       Size:         319640592384 B (319.4 GB)
       Free Space:   6111232 B (6.1 MB)
       |
       +-< Physical Volume 907FCDE2-0C62-4951-A39E-36F19244FDB7
       |   ----------------------------------------------------
       |   Index:    0
       |   Disk:     disk0s2
       |   Status:   Online
       |   Size:     319640592384 B (319.4 GB)
       |
       +-> Logical Volume Family 2FA7892F-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
           ----------------------------------------------------------
           Encryption Status:       Unlocked
           Encryption Type:         None
           Conversion Status:       NoConversion
           Conversion Direction:    -none-
           Has Encrypted Extents:   No
           Fully Secure:            No
           Passphrase Required:     No
           |
           +-> Logical Volume 7BF42B7B-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
               ---------------------------------------------------
               Disk:                  disk1
               Status:                Online
               Size (Total):          319282155520 B (319.0 GB)
               Conversion Progress:   -none-
               Revertible:            No
               LV Name:               Macintosh HD
               Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
               Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
   ```
4. Copy the Logical Volume Group (LVG) alphanumeric UUID of your CoreStorage volume. The LVG should be the first UUID listed and it’s the one you want to delete.
5. Next, run the following command:
   `diskutil cs delete UUID`
   In the above example: `diskutil cs delete 5B8350BF-20EF-4199-82E6-129EFF19E9EB`
   This will delete your CoreStorage volume and reformat it as an unencrypted HFS+ volume.
   Quit Terminal
6. In the now opening window choose `Disk Utility` and erase/partition the internal drive.

   [image: Diskutil]

   Choose your physical device in the left pane enter a name and format it `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`. If this isn't possible partition your physical device: `1 Partition` `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` click the `Options...` button and choose `GUID Partition Table` enter OK and Apply. Quit `Disk Utility`.
7. Plug in your `Time Machine` backup drive.
8. Start `Restore from Time Machine Backup` and recover your old system

   [image: TimeMachine]

**The dirty and risky way (no Time Machine backup):**

9. [Turn off File Vault 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18674). This may take several hours.
10. Use `Boot Camp Assistant` to remove the Windows installation. If this doesn't work continue with a reboot:
11. Start to `Internet Recovery Mode` by pressing  <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
12. In the now opening window choose `Disk Utility`
13. Remove disk0s5 by choosing it and clicking on <kbd>-</kbd>

    [image]
14. Try also to remove `Recovery HD`
15. Try to expand `Macintosh HD` to full size

If the last two steps don't work give me a comment

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used the non dirty unrisky way and everything went well except now... No recovery HD is there at all.  There are plenty of resources online about that though, thank you

Comment: @Xavier Before adding a Recovery HD with Recovery Partition Creator 3.8 check that you don't have a CoreStorage Volume with  `diskutil cs list`. I will add a description tomorrow. i have forgotten that.

Comment: I already looked around I have no CoreStorage Volume.  I have 1 more question.  What led to the CoreStorage Volume to being created and what are the benefits of it?  Thank you

Comment: Probably FileVault 2 was enabled. Your whole Macintosh HD volume was encrypted (=secure). Another purpose of CS is the creation of a FusionDrive.